# Fit content of a scrollview to the scrollview superview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have the following view hierarchy :

```
View1 (root view)
 Scrollview
  View2
```

I use auto-layout and I would like the view2 to fit to the view1 size.
In the past, to solve ambiguous scrollable content, I programmatically added a fixed constraint for the view2 width and height. 
But I would like to know there is a nicer way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually quite simple. Set two constraints linking `View2` and `Scrollview`(`Superview` actually) with `Equal Widths` and `Equal Heights`.
This can be done in the xib file or programmatically.